# If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ why does $\frac{a+c}{b + d} = \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Can anyone prove why adding the numerator and denominator of the same ratios result in the same ratio? For example, since $\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{2}{4}$ then $\dfrac{1+2}{2+4}=0.5$.

Comment: The answers below answer your question completely, but as a side note, this phenomenon is called [Componendo-Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that if you have two fractions $\frac ac$ and $\frac bd$, then the fraction $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ is called [mediant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)).

Comment: $\frac{a+b}{c+d}$ is between $\frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ so when the latter two are the same, so is the third

Comment: @Henry Don't get your dirty calculus in our clean algebra!  ;)

Comment: @Henry squeeze theorem isn't it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sketch: If you have $\frac{p}{q}$ and $\frac{\lambda p}{\lambda q}$, then
$$
\frac{p+\lambda p}{q+\lambda q}=\frac{(1+\lambda)p}{(1+\lambda)q}=\frac{p}{q}
$$
provided $1+\lambda\not=0$.

Answer (score 34):

Consider $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ka}{kb}$ Then, $$\frac{a+ka}{b+kb}=\frac{(k+1)a}{(k+1)b}=\frac{a}{b}$$
which is exactly what you noticed, but with $a=1,b=2,k=2$

Comment: Such a difference in up-votes for being a mere 25 seconds behind Michael!

Comment: @PaulSinclair I know, I even upvoted this one too!

Comment: -1 needs more $\lambda$

Comment: This answer lacks a condition on `k+1`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution, not to disparage the other answers.

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\quad&\Rightarrow\quad\frac{ad}{b}=c&\text{solve for $c$}\\
\frac{a+c}{b+d}&=\frac{a+\left(\frac{ad}{b}\right)}{b+d}&\text{substitute $c$}\\
&=a\cdot\frac{1+\left(\frac{d}{b}\right)}{b+d}&\text{factor $a$ from numerator}\\
&=a\cdot\frac{b+d}{b(b+d)}&\text{multiply by $\frac{b}{b}$}\\
&=\frac{a}{b}\quad\blacksquare&\text{cancel $(b+d)$}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

We know $ad=bc$, so $ab+bc=ab+ad$. If you factor out this equation you get $b(a+c)=a(b+d)$ and then you get $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$. Similarly, you can prove the other equality.

Answer (score 0):

Or, with less variables, you can treat your fraction as reducible to some number $a$ (e.g. a decimal), which you can write as $\frac{a}{1}$. Then:

$\frac{a+a}{1+1} = \frac{2a}{2} = \frac{a}{1} = a$