# Solving a PDE with Method of Characteristics.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am currently trying to solve a PDE using Method of Characteristics, but am having a bit of trouble. The PDE is given by:
$$xu_x+yu_y+zu_z=1$$
With Initial Conditions:
$$u=0 \text{ on } x+y+z=1$$
Now I computed the Characteristics:
$$x(s) = x_0 e^s, \>\>y(s) = y_0 e^s, \>\> z(s)=z_0 e^s$$
Where $x(0)=x_0$, and the analogous statement holds for $y_0, z_0$. Now, I don't get what the conclusion is. From these characteristics I get:
$$e^s = \frac{x}{x_0}$$
And the same for the $y$ and $z$ cases, but what can I conclude about $u$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Characteristics_of_first-order_partial_differential_equation), we can write out the characteristic ODEs as

$$\frac{dx}{x} \stackrel{(1)}= \frac{dy}{y} \stackrel{(2)}= \frac{dz}{z} \stackrel{(3)}= \frac{du}{1}$$

Solving equality $(1)$ yields

\begin{align}
\ln y &= \ln x + c_{0} \\
\implies y &= c_{0} x \\
\implies \frac{y}{x} &= c_{0} \quad (4)
\end{align}

Using [Componendo-Dividendo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251426/if-displaystyle-a-over-b-c-over-d-why-does-displaystyle-ac-over-b/2260910#2260910) on equality $(1)$ and setting equal to $(2)$ yields

\begin{align}
\frac{dx + dy}{x + y} &= \frac{d (x + y)}{x + y} \quad \text {(C.D)}\\
&= \frac{dz}{z} \\
\implies \ln(x + y) &= \ln z + c_{1} \\
\implies \frac{x + y}{z} &= c_{1} \quad (5)
\end{align}

Using [Componendo-Dividendo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251426/if-displaystyle-a-over-b-c-over-d-why-does-displaystyle-ac-over-b/2260910#2260910) on equalities $(1)$ and $(2)$ and setting equal to $(3)$ yields

\begin{align}
\frac{dx + dy + dz}{x + y + z} &= \frac{d (x + y + z)}{x + y + z} \quad \text {(C.D)}\\
&= \frac{du}{1} \\
\implies \ln(x + y + z) &= u + c_{2} \\
\implies \ln(x + y + z) - u &= c_{2} \quad (6)
\end{align}

Hence, the solution is given implicitly by

\begin{align}
\phi(c_{0}, c_{1}, c_{2}) &= 0 \\
\implies \phi \left( \frac{y}{x}, \frac{x + y}{z}, \ln(x + y + z) - u \right) &= 0 \\
\end{align}

where $\phi$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. We can also write this as

$$\ln(x + y + z) - u = f \left( \frac{y}{x}, \frac{x + y}{z} \right)$$

where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. You can then apply your initial condition to determine $f$ and get the full solution (you should find $f \equiv 0$).