# How to Solve this Lagrange's Linear equation and find the integral surface?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I need help in solving this problem

> Find the general solution of the partial differential equation
>   $$x(z+2a)p+(xz+2yz+2ay)q=z(z+a),$$
>   where $p = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$. Also find its particular integral surface which passes through the given curve $y=0$, $z^2=4ax$.

I know this is a Lagrange's linear equation and that I require two general solution of this equation to find the Integral surface.

I got the first general solution like this
$$\frac{dx}{x(z+2a)}=\frac{dy}{xz+2yz+2ay}=\frac{dz}{z(z+a)}$$
comparing 1st and 3rd we get
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{(z+2a)dz}{z(z+a)}$$
Integrating this we get the first solution
$$\frac{z^2}{x(z+a)}=c_1.$$
I just can not find the second solution , I have tried substituting 
$$x=\frac{z^2}{c_1(z+a)}$$ while equating the 2nd and 3rd equation but it gets much more complex.

Can you find the second solution?

Comment: Using [Componendo-Dividendo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251426/if-displaystyle-a-over-b-c-over-d-why-does-displaystyle-ac-over-b/2260910#2260910) on the first equality yields

\begin{align}
\frac{dx + dy}{2xz + 2yz + 2ax + 2ay} &= \frac{d (x + y)}{(2a + 2z)(x + y)} \quad \text {(C.D)}\\
&= \frac{dz}{z(z + a)} \\
\implies \frac{d (x + y)}{x + y} &= \frac{2 dz}{z} \\
\implies \ln(x + y) &= \ln(z^{2}) + c_{1} \\
\implies \frac{x + y}{z^{2}} &= c_{1}
\end{align}