# I can't understand the 'ignored' step in this PDE - characteristics method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I've just solved my first pde with the method of characteristics. The textbook I'm following gives many examples and this pde is one of them : 
$$x^2u_x+y^2u_y=(x+y)u$$

Applying the equation : $$\frac{dx}{a(x,y)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y)}=\frac{du}{f(x,y)}$$

in this case we get:  $$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{du}{(x+y)u}$$

From the last equation the author claims this:

$$\frac{dx-dy}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{du}{(x+y)u}$$

How is this true?

Comment: It's called [compendo-dividendo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251426/if-dfracab-dfraccd-why-does-dfracacb-d-dfracab/2260910#2260910).

Comment: It's a very common identity $$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a+c}{b+d} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple. We have :

$$dx=\frac{x^2du}{(x+y)u}$$
$$dy=\frac{y^2du}{(x+y)u}$$

Subtracting these two gives: 
$$dx-dy=\frac{(x^2-y^2)du}{(x+y)u}$$
$$=>\frac{dx-dy}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{du}{(x+y)u}$$