# Stuck solving this PDE problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve $$uu_x+yu_y=x, u(x,1)=2x$$ i tried with characteristics method but got stuck solving the ODEs $$\frac{dx}{dt}=u ~,~\frac{dy}{dt}=y~,~\frac{du}{dt}=x$$ with initial values $x(0)=s,y(0)=1,u(0)=2s$. From the second one i get $y=e^t$, but how to solve the first two ODEs? I tried $$\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{u}{x} \implies x^2-u^2=k_1$$ where $k_1=-3s^2$ which gives $u=\sqrt{x^2+3s^2}$. Similarly $$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+3s^2}} \implies y=k_2(x+\sqrt{x^2+3s^2})$$ And $k_2$ can be found out as $k_2=\frac{1}{3s}$, giving me $y=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+3s^2}}{3s}$. I'm not sure how to proceed further and solve for $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier if we write the ODEs in the [parametrisation invariant form of the Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Characteristics_of_first-order_partial_differential_equation)

$$\frac{dx}{u} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{du}{x}$$

You correctly identified the first characteristic curve

$$\frac{dx}{u} = \frac{du}{x} \implies u^{2} - x^{2} = C_{2}$$

Now, we can use [componendo dividendo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251426/if-dfracab-dfraccd-why-does-dfracacb-d-dfracab/2260910#2260910) on the first and third fractions to get

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{u} = \frac{du}{x} &= \frac{du+dx}{u+x} \\
&= \frac{d(u+x)}{u+x} \\
&= \frac{dy}{y} \\
\end{align}

and so solving the last equality and using the functional relationship $C_{2} = f(C_{1})$ yields

\begin{align}
\ln(u+x) &= \ln y + C_{1} \\
\implies \frac{u+x}{y} &= C_{1} \\
\implies u^{2} - x^{2} &= f(C_{1}) \\
&= f \left(\frac{u+x}{y}\right)
\end{align}

which you can check solves the PDE. Now you can apply the data $u(x,1) = 2x$.

Comment: But i'm not able to write $u(x,y)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You have $$u(x,1)^{2}-x^{2} = f \left(\frac{u(x,1)+x}{1} \right) \implies 3x^{2} = f(3x)$$ and letting $3x = X$ $$\implies f(X) = \frac{X^{2}}{3} \implies f \left(\frac{u+x}{y} \right) = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{u+x}{y} \right)^{2}$$ Then solve for $u$.

Answer (score 1):

According to your results we have

$$
\cases{
u^2-x^2-3s^2=0\\
y-\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+3s^2}}{3s}=0
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
u^2-x^2-3s^2=0\\
(3sy-x)^2-x^2-3s^2=0
}
$$

So solving the first for $s$ and substituting after choosing the feasible one into the second, we have

$$
u = x\frac{3y^2+1}{3y^2-1}
$$

Comment: something seems to be wrong in your calculations. I'm not able to write $u$ as per your answer.

Comment: It can be written also as $$u=x\left(1+\frac{2}{3y^2-1}\right)$$

Comment: Still it's not possible to write this, it's a nonlinear equation you cant separate u in terms of x and y @cesareo

Comment: I can as long as the former equations are true. Did you verify if this solution obeys the PDE with initial conditions?

Comment: It's clear from two equations i got, that : $u=-x+y\sqrt{3(u^2-x^2)}$. How can one express $u$ from here as functions of $x,y$ only? It's clearly not possible

Comment: Solving for $u$ we get two solutions: $u = -x$ and $u = x\left(\frac{3y^2+1}{3y^2-1}\right)$. The second obeys the initial conditions, as wel as the PDE.