# Get value of $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ from the values of $\frac{a}b$ and $\frac{c}d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, this seems easy, but I cannot figure it out, and I haven't been able to find a similar problem when searching around.

Let $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{c}{d}$, and $z=\frac{a+c}{b+d}$, where $a,b,c,d >0$ are real numbers. If I know the values of $x$ and $y$ (i.e., not the numerators and denominators), can I get the value of $z$?

I've tried some different things without much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{3}$.  Then, $y=\frac{\lambda}{3\lambda}$ for any $\lambda\not=0$.  So, we can let $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=\lambda$, and $d=3\lambda$.  Observe that
$$
z=\frac{1+\lambda}{2+3\lambda}.
$$

- When $\lambda=1$, $z=\frac{2}{5}$.
- When $\lambda=2$, $z=\frac{3}{8}$.

Since the value of $z$ changes, depending on $\lambda$, then there's nothing that you can say without knowing more about $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

If $x=y$, then this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251426/if-dfracab-dfraccd-why-does-dfracacb-d-dfracab/2251434#2251434) of mine shows that you can calculate $z$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved me a bunch of time bashing my head against the wall.

Comment: Always try an example since it's usually a quick and easy thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

- If $x\le y$, I claim that $$x \le z \le y $$
  To see it note that $x \le y$ is equivalent to $ad \le bc$.

Now $x \le z$ is just $\frac{a}{b} \le \frac{a+c}{b+d}$ which is just $ad\le bc$.

Similarly $z\le y$ is just $\frac{a+c}{b+d}\le \frac{c}{d} $, which is also $ad\le bc$.

However, as the other example shows, we can't determine the solution uniquely.

Comment: Nice, but not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/205654